# sqlserver query on very large DB faster after DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Tags: sql-server

I ran a query on a very large DB and it took 1.2 mins to complete.

I then ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

and the same query only took 6 seconds!

I had assumed that FREEPROCCACHE would, if anything, make it run slower...

Why has this query sped up?

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect it to run slower? It seems you might be the victim of the "[parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)" problem.

`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` cleans the part of the SQL Server memory that caches execution plans for stored procedures and queries.

That is, every time you run a stored procedure, it will look in the cache to see if it already generated an execution plan for it and use it, without recalculating it (**except if** you have the RECOMPILE option mentioned either at the query level or at the top of the stored procedure definition).

If you did that, the next time you ran your query/procedure the SQL Server is `FORCED` to look at statistics and other metadata it has available and not use the cached (and probably old and stale) execution plan and can generate a much better execution plan, that works for your new database situation.

Database situation can include:

- indexes (new or updated)
- more or less data
- new table/column statistics
- and more

`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` cleans the RAM memory of the SQL Server of all the datapages cached (previously read from disk). If you would run this command, then I can almost **guarantee** that your next query will run slower, because it will have to read all of those pages from disk back into RAM (where it will cache them for further executions).

However, **never run `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` in a production environment!** (only in an isolated test or development **server**)

**Update:**

If you do want to run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` in production, you can target it to clean the cached execution plan for a single query or procedure, just by specifying a plan or query handle.

If we look at the [documentation of `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Removes all elements from the plan cache, removes a specific plan from
>   the plan cache by specifying a plan handle or SQL handle, or removes
>   all cache entries associated with a specified resource pool.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer thank you. Actually, I call my query from C#. The DB grows by millions of rows each day. Should I add OPTION(RECOMPILE) to C# query? A quick read suggests this is not necessary, but I wonder if that would be best as I do not tend to query DB much from within SSMS. Or I could run a sched task each night to just do "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE" before my C# Apps start processing?

Comment: I would suggest to continue as what your quick reading suggests, don't add it, just yet. Recompilation can sometimes cause more problems.

Comment: Or I could run a sched task each night to just do "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE" before my C# Apps start processing?

Comment: Clearing the cache might not always be the solution. You might have to end up tuning your query or applying other techniques. It's hard to say at this point what is the best thing you should do. I can only give an answer to your posted question, I can't pick the best option for you. This actually takes some careful analysis.